# How to create SPWebApplication (SharePoint Web Application) programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I wonder how can I create  SPWebApplication (SharePoint 2010 and 2013 ) programmatically?
Do I need a Remote Administration using Sharepoint 2010 Management Shell or there is c# code.

best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example code using C#.Net

```
// Create  new object of SPWebApplication & SPWebApplicationBuilder class
SPWebApplication newApplication;
SPWebApplicationBuilder webAppBuilder = new SPWebApplicationBuilder(SPFarm.Local);

// Set necessary values to webAppBuilder object

webAppBuilder.Port = portNo;
webAppBuilder.RootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(D:\projects\TestWebSite3030);
webAppBuilder.ApplicationPoolId = appPoolId;
webAppBuilder.ApplicationPoolUsername = appPoolUserName;
webAppBuilder.ApplicationPoolPassword = password;
webAppBuilder.CreateNewDatabase = true;
webAppBuilder.DatabaseServer = dbServerName; // DB server name
webAppBuilder.DatabaseName = dbName;// DB Name
if (isSQLAuth)
{
webAppBuilder.DatabaseUsername = dbUid; // dbUid is username of the DB sever
webAppBuilder.DatabasePassword = dbPwd; // dbpassword is password of the DB sever
}
webAppBuilder.UseNTLMExclusively = true;  // authentication provider for NTLM
webAppBuilder.AllowAnonymousAccess = isAnonymous; // anonymous access permission

// Finally create web application
newApplication = webAppBuilder.Create(); 
newApplication.Provision();
```

[Source](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Create-SharePoint-Web-Application-Programmatically-87.php)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use PowerShell

[New-SPWebApplication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607931%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Taken from Technet

Creates a new Web application specified by the Name parameter. The user specified by the DatabaseCredentials parameter must be a member of the dbcreator fixed server role on the database server.

This example creates a new Web application by using an internal host header of sharepoint.contoso.com and a public URL of https://www.contoso.com

```
$ap = New-SPAuthenticationProvider
New-SPWebApplication -Name "Contoso Internet Site" -Port 443 -HostHeader sharepoint.contoso.com -URL "https://www.contoso.com" -ApplicationPool "ContosoAppPool" -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount "DOMAIN\jdoe") -AuthenticationProvider $ap -SecureSocketsLayer
```

Comment: seems like we were typing at the same time :-)

Comment: Indeed we do ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can create it in both C# and PowerShell. Example of PS command:

```
New-SPWebApplication -Name "Contoso Internet Site" -Port 443 -HostHeader sharepoint.contoso.com -URL "https://www.contoso.com" -ApplicationPool "ContosoAppPool" -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount "DOMAIN\jdoe") -AuthenticationProvider $ap -SecureSocketsLayer
```

See more at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607931(v=office.15).aspx

The C# code is already provided by @Karthik Jaganathan